# PHP jpeg image created from file is low quality

Tags: php, image, compression

This code randomly generates an image from an array. It works fine, but the image is compressed heavily. Is there a way to keep the quality?

```
$img = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg' ); // Adds images into an array
$i = rand(0, count($img)-1); // Generates a random number (max being the last elements index from the array)
$chosenimg = "$img[$i]"; // Sets the variable $chosenimg to equal to whatever the random image was
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($chosenimg);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: The default value for image quality is 75. To change it to 100 (best quality) you need to change `imagejpeg($image);` to `imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) :

`bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, mixed $to [, int $quality ]] )`

so you have to change `imagejpeg($image);` with `imagejpeg($image, null, 100);` to get the best quality.